# Add horizontal scroll Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, game-engine

I want to design my levels on a horizontal pane what i am doing is:

```
 container = new Table(skin);
    container.setBounds(0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    levelselect = new Table(skin);
    levelselect.setBounds(0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
 //   list = new List(skin,"1");

    scrollPane = new ScrollPane(levelselect);
    scrollPane.layout();
    levelselect.align(Align.left);
    for(int i=1;i<20;i++){
        levelnumber = new Label(" "+i,levelnumbertext);
        levelselect.add(levelnumber);

    }



    container.align(Align.bottom);

    container.add(scrollPane).width(400).height(400);
    container.add(levelselect);
```

any suggestions?? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `ScrollPane` and `Table` for this sounds like a lot of unnecessary overhead, they have a lot going on in the background, dynamically calculating their own layouts etc, you might not need this if you just want a full screen side scroller. You might be best just positioning your `Actors` on the `Stage`, however far along they need to be and update the `Camera` position to suit. `Stage` has culling options which I think by default are enabled, so it won't be drawing any of your `Actors` that are off the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your response...i did it by adding a scrollpane on a table and then this scrollpane in a container table and then i disabled y-axis scroll and it worked...:)